# How to add python 2.7 in yocto sdk

Tags: python-2.7, yocto, bitbake

I am using Yocto thud release. I have an application which is using Python 2.7.so in cmake. I know how to add python 2.7 in an image. But I want to make sdk. By default my sdk has Python 3.5. When I try cross-compile my application with sdk it gives error of unable to find Python2.

My cmake is looking for this package

```
find_package(PythonLibs 2 REQUIRED)
```

My target architecture is RaspberryPi.

Probably I have to add something in

> TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK

or

> TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK